# Python - BeautifulSoup4 decompose() isn't working

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, lxml

I'm trying to get categories from this page for all title.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) \
         AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) \
         Ubuntu Chromium/33.0.1750.152 Chrome/33.0.1750.152 Safari/537.36'
}
category_url = ''
html = urllib2.urlopen(urllib2.Request(category_url, None, headers)).read()
page = BeautifulSoup(html)
results = page.find('div', {'class': "results"}).find_all('li')

for res in results:
    category = res.find(attrs={'class': "category"}) or res.find(attrs={'class': "categories"})
    #print category  #till here, I'm getting correct data
    print category.b.decompose() #here is the problem? I should get the div element without <b> tag but it returns None
```

I'm getting `None` instead of updated dom.

PS: If you have any suggestion to improve this code please let me know.I would be happy to make changes for better performance and pythonic code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decompose removes the tag from the tree, *and returns None*, not the remaining tree. This is similar to the way `list.append` and `list.sort` work. (These methods also modify the caller and return `None`.)

```
for res in results:
    category = res.find(attrs={'class': "category"}) or res.find(attrs={'class': "categories"})
    category.b.decompose()
    print(category)
```

yields output like

```
<div class="categories">

<span class="highlighted">Advertising</span> <span class="highlighted">Agencies</span> </div>
```

---

Using lxml:

```
import lxml.html as LH
import urllib2

category_url = 'http://www.localsearch.ae/en/category/Advertising-Agencies/1013'
doc = LH.parse(urllib2.urlopen(category_url))    
for category in doc.xpath(
    '//div[@class="category"]|//div[@class="categories"]'):
    b = category.find('b')
    category.remove(b)
    print(LH.tostring(category))
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you find any need of improvements. as for category I'm using `or` for two different class. Is there any better way to do this.

Comment: From the tags I see you have `lxml`, so I would just use XPath (see above).